# How does this nested loop get to this output?

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I have struggled to understand the output of this nested loop for a long time. I really want to understand what it does.

I would expect it to output: `[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]`

But the actual output is: `[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]`

After the first inner loop `row` contains two 0's and should be pushed to the `newArray` in the outer loop. It looks like this isn't happenening and I can't figure out why. The first element should be `[0, 0]`, right?.

I really hope someone can see what I mean here and explain what's happening! Thank you!

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {

  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: `    let copy = [...row]
    newArray.push(copy);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because JavaScript objects (and arrays), are just a reference in memory. so you are creating a single array of arrays that share the same address in memory, because they share the same address, when you update it (Array.prototype.push), you are updating all of them. The solution is to create a new row in the first loop:

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {  
  const newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // If this isn't the first run, take the last value of row
    const prevRow = i > 0 ? newArray[i-1] : [];
    const row = [...prevRow]; // By using the spread operator(...), you can copy an array

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

### Important note

This isn't a natural way of writing JavaScript, you can achive the same with:

```js
const zeroArray = (m, n) => Array.from({ length : m }).map((value, index) => {
  return Array.from({ length : (index + 1) * n }).map(() => 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `row` to all the iterations of the loop. To achieve what you want, row must be unique through each iteration of the loop, so you need to move it inside the first loop.

To better understand the issue, read more about values and by references in JavaScript: [https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/#:~:text=JavaScript%20pass%2Dby%2Dvalue%20or%20pass%2Dby%2Dreference&text=It%20means%20that%20JavaScript%20copies,variables%20outside%20of%20the%20function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20pass%2Dby%2Dvalue%20or%20pass%2Dby%2Dreference&text=It%20means%20that%20JavaScript%20copies,variables%20outside%20of%20the%20function).

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {

  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    let row = [];
  
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
    // Update n to get desired pattern
    n += 2
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to fix the issue but I just can't figure out why it does what it does... Why doesn't it push an element with two 0's after the inner loop has completed the first time? And then in the second inner loop add two more 0's to `row` & add this element to the array? I don't see how it first creates a `row` with six 0's before pushing it to `newArray`. It doesn't make sense to me yet.

Comment: To be clear: after the inner loop completes, I would expect the outer loop to also complete. In this case you would get `newArray = [ [0,0] ]` after the first inner & outer loop. Right?

Comment: It would be, but when you add to `row` in the next loop, the `[0,0]` at index 0 becomes `[0,0,0,0]` on the next loop, and `[0,0,0,0,0,0]` on the final loop.

Thinking of it like this will probably help: `newArray = [x,x,x]`. If you assign `x = [0,0]` on the first loop, then `x = [0,0,0,0]` on the second loop, of course the `x` at index 0 will have the same value as the `x` at index 1. It's a bit confusing because this isn't the case with primitives, but it could be if javascript had pointers to primitives.